# Simpliest javascript search on a specific site obtaining value from a textbox

Tags: javascript, forms, search, button, onclick

What im trying to do is to make a simple textbox/button to search on youtube, the simpliest way possible.

The JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search()
var value = getelementbyid="search-box"
openinanewwindow = https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='value'
</script>
```

The html

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="search-box">
<input type="button" id="search-btn" value="Search" onClick="search()">
</form>
```

Please ignore the way i wrote the script i just tried to explain my objective the simplest way possible and i know i didn't applied any real/correct terms.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="search-box"></input>
    <input type="button" id="search-btn" value="Search"></input>
</form>

document.getElementById("search-btn").onclick=function(){
        var value=document.getElementById("search-box").value;
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+value);
}
```

Comment: Its not working, when i click the button nothing happens, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome but i think the browser is not relevant as im testing it on jsfiddle and its not working http://jsfiddle.net/Minnen/RSdEZ/

Comment: Change on Frameworks & Extensions from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`

Comment: awesome, now it did worked on jsfiddle, however if i try to use it on my site it doesn't work, here's the complete html http://pastebin.com/sYPqfHpF

Comment: Try putting your script below body

Comment: still not working, might be a pop-up block? should i set it to open on current window?

Comment: done, working on jsfiddle but not working on the site, tried with the js before and after the body no success.

Comment: In your site the id of the button is btn-search, change it to search-btn and change box-search to search-box

Comment: update, i dont know how this can be possible but it worked only 1 time and then it didnt work anymore. html http://pastebin.com/Mc8V1zWM

Comment: update 2, if i execute the html alone it works but as this is a google chrome esxtension i have to set the permissions right, the code workes properly ignore update 1